# How to make NextAuth.js work with SSG (static site generated) in a Next.js website

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth, static-site-generation

Next.js allows you to build your site with either server-side (SSR) or static client-side (SSG) rendering, but when you run `next build && next export` it removes the `/api` routes.

Since NextAuth.js relies on these routes to for `/api/auth/signin` for example, how can you implement NextAuth.js for SSG?

Comment: API Routes can't be used with `next export`, you'll need to have a running server using `next build && next start` instead.

Comment: @juliomalves but surely NextAuth.js is designed to work with SSG? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -3):

Yes `next-auth` can validate both backend and frontend.
The function you want is [`getSession()`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#getsession) which is available both on the backend and frontend. However you cannot do that with statically generated sites, as they are evaluated on build. You can do that with serverside rendering though.

Here is a sample Server Side rendered Page Auth Guard

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/login",
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

**Here is a sample API auth**

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client"

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req })
  /* ... */
  res.end()
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer.

Comment: i highly doubt that it's safe or possible to use `getSession` on the client